# Constraints and collisions with map regions using SpriteKit and GamePlayKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

I'm building a 2D game using SpriteKit and GamePlayKit where units move around the map. One of the things I want to implement is get a notification when a land unit enters specific region of the map (Dot 1). Second thing is constraining warships to only move on the water.

[image]

So my initial idea was to make the whole land on my map one SpriteNode (let's call it A) and the interesting green region another SpriteNode. So if I add physicsBodies to them I can quickly check in `didBegin` if there's a collision or not. But I'm not sure how this would work with the GPK entity system which introduces it's own physics. Anyone has any experience with that ? I found something similar mentioned in Apple's docs : https://developer.apple.com/reference/gameplaykit/gkpolygonobstacle

> If you’re already using nodes with physics bodies to keep sprites from
>   entering those regions, you can reuse those nodes.

so this seems to be a viable option after all.

Comment: So what is the problem here? Generally you should make each region to have different physics category. Also you may want to create node's physics body from a texture.

Comment: As I said, I'm concerned about the fact that GamePlayKit sets it's own mass and acceleration. But I think I'll just take a shot with this approach.